# Neo4j / Cypher: Matching "Triangles"

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and Cypher and I can't get my head around this problem.
Let's suppose I have a very large graph with 3 different node types: Doctor, Diagnosis and Product.
I would like to do the following thing:

For each Doctor-Diagnosis connected pair, count how many different products are linked to both the doctor and the diagnosis.

A sample of my data would be:

```
Doctor_ID   Diagnosis   Product
   1           A          123
   1           B          527
   1           A          198
   2           K          471
   2           A          123
   3           J          024
   3           A          198
   3           A          123
   3           A          722
```

And I would like to get:

```
Doctor_ID    Diagnosis   COUNT 
   1            A          2
   1            B          1
   2            K          1
   2            A          1
   3            J          1
   3            A          3
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: can you give us sample data to work on? Thanks

Comment: How did you model your data?

Comment: I mapped into a Knowledge Graph with py2neo. Each line of the dataset is mapped into 3 connected nodes, then nodes are of course merged based on their ID. I also have some more node features but it is not relevant

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional information about the schema, I would suggest the following query:

```
MATCH (d:Doctor)--(d1:Diagnosis)
MATCH (d)--(:Product)--(d1)
RETURN count(*) AS commonProducts
```

Comment: This actually returns zero. I'm now editing the question to add data